# svg won't show text containing g tags

Tags: html, svg, latex, tikz, tspan

I have reduced my problem to a minimal working example. This code snippet won't show any text:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?> 
<svg viewBox="-361.65944 -228.02199 723.31888 284.92749 ">
    <text > 
        <g fill="#000">
            <g stroke="none">
                <tspan font-family="cmr" font-size="17">Render</tspan>
                <tspan font-family="cmr" font-size="17">Process</tspan>
            </g>
        </g>
    </text> 
</svg>
```

Now, if I comment out the two `g` tags, the text is shown:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?> 
<svg viewBox="-361.65944 -228.02199 723.31888 284.92749 ">
    <text > 
        <!-- <g fill="#000"> -->
            <!-- <g stroke="none"> -->
                <tspan font-family="cmr" font-size="17">Render</tspan>
                <tspan font-family="cmr" font-size="17">Process</tspan>
            <!-- </g> -->
        <!-- </g> -->
    </text> 
</svg>
```

Why does it happen? I am generating the svg via `htlatex` out of the following tikz document:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    main/.style={rounded corners, fill=blue!15, align=center, inner sep=10, text width=6cm, minimum height=4cm, font={\fontsize{50 pt}{40 pt}\selectfont}},
    render/.style={rounded corners, fill=red!15, align=center, inner sep=6, text width=5cm, minimum height=3.5cm, font={\fontsize{40 pt}{40 pt}\selectfont}},
]
    \node[main] (main) {Main Process};
    \node[render] [below=of main, xshift=10cm, yshift=-1.5cm] (render1) {Render Process};
    \node[render] [below=of main, xshift=3.2cm, yshift=-1.5cm] (render2) {Render Process};
    \node[render] [below=of main, xshift=-3.2cm, yshift=-1.5cm] (render3) {...};
    \node[render] [below=of main, xshift=-10cm, yshift=-1.5cm] (render4) {Render Process};

    \draw [->] (main) -- (render1.north);
    \draw [->] (main) -- (render2.north);
    \draw [->] (main) -- (render3.north);
    \draw [->] (main) -- (render4.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have no clue what is going on here. I would really appreciate any kind of input!

Comment: Why do you try to nest g elements inside a `<text>`?

Comment: @enxaneta I do not know much about SVG, this file was generated using `htlatex` from a latex document :( Is it forbidden to use `g` tags inside a `<text>`?

Comment: Yes it's forbidden.

Comment: The text elements can contain any number of the following elements, in any order:
animation elements 
descriptive elements 
text content child elements — ‘altGlyph’, ‘textPath’, ‘tref’, ‘tspan’
‘a’ https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html

Comment: altGlyph and tref are removed from SVG 2 though.

Comment: Is this a bug in htlatex that you need to report to its maintainers?

Comment: With `latex document ; dvisvgm document.dvi` you can directly compile to svg, no need to involve htlatex

Answer (score 0):

`htlatex` is not the best tool for producing a svg file out of a latex file. `pdf2svg` works better. To convert your `tex` file to `svg`:

1. Compile your latex to pdf, using e.g. `latexmk -pdf main.tex`
2. Convert the output pdf to svg using `pdf2svg`: `pdf2svg main.pdf main.svg`

The resulting `svg` will not contain the bugs that you would find using `htlatex main.tex` to produce the `svg`